# super() doesn't work in classmethod

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes, metaclass

`ctypes` has a classmethod [from_buffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer). I'm trying to add some custom processing to `from_buffer()` in a subclass, but I'm having trouble calling `super()`. Here is an example:

```
from ctypes import c_char, Structure


class Works(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("char", c_char),
    ]


class DoesntWork(Works):
    @classmethod
    def from_buffer(cls, buf):
        print "do some extra stuff"
        return super(DoesntWork, cls).from_buffer(buf)


print Works.from_buffer(bytearray('c')).char
print DoesntWork.from_buffer(bytearray('c')).char
```

This results in the error:

```
c
do some extra stuff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "superctypes.py", line 18, in <module>
    print DoesntWork.from_buffer(bytearray('c')).char
  File "superctypes.py", line 14, in from_buffer
    return super(DoesntWork, cls).from_buffer(buf)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'from_buffer'
```

What am I missing? Why doesn't super work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from_buffer` is not actually a class method on `Structure`; it is a method on `Structure`'s type (that is, its metaclass).  As such, it can't be overridden in the usual fashion: it's like asking to override a normal method for a single *object*, not a *class*.

Calling `type(cls).from_buffer(cls,buf)` works.  It's pretty terrible, but I don't immediately see another option.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might be an artifact of the metaclass, but I couldn't figure out how to work around it. This technique works great.

Comment: I don't think it is that terrible. It is better than subclassing the metaclass itself just for doing that, for sure.